# How can I use array.indexOf with a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

```
var items = [LiveCellProtocol]() //unsorted array

public class User: LiveCellProtocol {
...
}

let mike = User()
items.append(mike)
items.indexOf(mike) //throws an error
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'LiveCellProtocol' to expected argument
>   type '@noescape (LiveCellProtocol) throws -> Bool'

How can I solve this problem? I really want to use the method `.indexOf`.  Is there a solution to this?

Right now, I'm hacking the solution by iterating through every item, and it's linear time.

Comment: `indexOf()` requires linear time as well ...

Comment: @MartinR are you sure indexOf is linear time? I thought swift has its own map for each array?

Comment: I am pretty sure. An array is not a dictionary. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:Ps14CollectionType: `Complexity: O(self.count).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `indexOf` in a protocol, it has to be `Equatable`. Conform your protocol to it and you'll be able to use it. For more info, take a look [here](http://blog.inferis.org/blog/2015/05/27/swift-an-array-of-protocols/).

Comment: Umm, doesn't the blog you linked to say you *cannot* do that? If I try doing this I get a pile of `Protocol ... can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` errors wherever I try to cast into that protocol.

Answer (score -1):

As you stated in the question you are interested in better than linear access to elements. I would recommend to consider following ordered array (with unique items).

This structure provides `indexOf` method which has logarithmic complexity. If that's helpful we can optimize this by eliminating recursion for instance (better to use loop instead).

```
public class OrderedArray<T: Comparable>
{
    var a = Array<T>()

    func append(item: T) {

        if let _ = indexOf(item) {
            //already exists
            return
        }
        a.append(item)
        a.sortInPlace()
    }

    func indexOf(item: T) -> Int? {

        //do logoriphmic search
        return searchItemIndex(item, start: 0, end: a.count - 1)
    }

    func searchItemIndex(item: T, start: Int, end: Int) -> Int? {

        if (start > end) {
            return nil
        }

        let m = (start + end) / 2

        if a[m] > item {

            return searchItemIndex(item, start: start, end: m - 1)
        } else if a[m] < item {

            return searchItemIndex(item, start: m + 1, end: end)
        } else {

            return m
        }
    }

    func objectAt(index: Int) -> T {

        return a[index]
    }

    var count: Int {

        return a.count
    }
}
```

CLEINTS CODE:

```
public func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {

    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

public func <(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id < rhs.id
}

public func >(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id > rhs.id
}

public func <=(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id <= rhs.id
}

public func >=(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id >= rhs.id
}

public class User: Comparable {

    var id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}


var users = OrderedArray<User>()

let mike = User(id: 1)
let john = User(id: 2)
let ash = User(id: 3)
let sam = User(id: 4)
let lens = User(id: 5)


users.append(mike)
users.append(ash)
users.append(john)
users.append(mike)
users.append(lens)

if let index = users.indexOf(lens) {
    print("User with id found:  \(users.objectAt(index).id)")
} else {
    print("User not found")
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean to hurt anybody with this. I would appreciate If there is any observation / suggestion for improvement :)